# Existe algum atalho para indentar o código no Sublime 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3, indentação

É de se perceber que em diversas IDE's existem alguns atalhos para [indentar o código](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Como por exemplo:

- Eclipse(Win): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Android Studio(Win): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Como todos* sabem, presumo eu, a indentação organiza visualmente o código de forma que os blocos dependentes fiquem alinhados, facilitando o entendimento e leitura.

Um exemplo do código abaixo **sem indetação**:

```
          <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" 
class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin</a>
</div>
```

Agora **com indentação**:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin</a>
</div>
```

Existe algum atalho ou "macete" para indentar o código no Sublime 3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Basta adicionar esta linha ao seu arquivo "Key Bindings - User" (localizado em Preferences > Keybindings - User )

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Fonte: https://coderwall.com/p/7yxpdw/auto-indenting-on-sublime-text-3

Lista de argumentos: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html?highlight=key%20binding

Comment: Existe outras alternativas na regra para esse json que você enviou? Por exemplo vi que ali possui `args`, teria outras formas de fazer seguindo esse padrão?

Comment: @AckLay aqui tem uma lista na documentacao http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html?highlight=key%20binding

Answer (score 12):

Não vem por padrão um atalho para esse comando (pelo menos não vinha).

O que pode fazer é adicionar um atalho personalizado: `Preferences` -> `Key bindings`, e na aba da direita (custom), adicionar algo assim:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent"}
```

Assim está o meu: utilizo bastante o `ctrl+shift+r` para reindentação quando colo um código de fora (tem que ajustar a linguagem antes para funcionar com um arquivo novo não salvo).

Outra maneira é usar o comando `ctrl+shift+p` (*goto anything*, um faz tudo), que eu uso bastante também. Você digita parte do comando ( `reindent`, `word wrap`) e ele mostra as opções.

Answer (score 4):

Vá no menu <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Key bindings</kbd>

Vai aparecer duas abas,na aba da direita(custom), você informa o código abaixo.

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+k+d"],"command": "reindent"}
```

Ou outro do seu gosto, caso seja outro, verifique se na aba da direita existe esse comando. No meu caso se eu pressionar somente as teclas <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> ele indenta.

OBS: Para o código ser indentado você tem que selecionar, ele não é como outras IDEs que você não precisar selecionar o código.
Espero ter ajudado.

Logo abaixo um GIF com o exemplo usado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]